# How do you write a 2 dimensional array in a function prototype?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this:
void displayBoard(char [][]);
(this is a function prototype)

shows the error: "May not have elements of this type".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in c++ use `vector<vector<int>> v` and make your life better

Comment: No of columns is mandatory.it is useful to compute the relative offset

Comment: @aaronman -- since OP wants parameter type as 'char [][]', expect 'vector<string>' should be sufficient.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take a multi-dimensional array as a parameter without providing the number of elements for each dimension. You have a few options available depending on how are managing the board data.

If the array size is dynamic you can use `std::vector`

```
void displayBoard(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& board);
```

If the array size is fixed and you know the size ahead of time you can include the size in the parameter or use `std::array`.

```
// Fixed size, naked array
void displayBoard(int (&board)[100][100]);

// Fixed size using std::array
void displayBoard(std::array<std::array<int, 100>, 100>& board);
```

If the arrays being passed to the function are fixed in size but you want to pass different sized arrays you can use a template.

```
// Fixed size, naked array
template<size_t Columns, size_t Rows>
void displayBoard(int (&board)[Rows][Columns]);

// Fixed size using std::array
template<size_t Columns, size_t Rows>
void displayBoard(std::array<std::array<int, Columns>, Rows>& board);
```

In all cases I recommend you pass them by reference to avoid unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because the function `displayBoard` would not have any information about the size of the dimensions of the array.

Your best option is to use a `std::vector` - you can nest vectors to get multiple-dimensions, and they carry information about their size within them.

For example,

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> blah; // two-dimensional vector of ints
displayBoard(blah);

void displayBoard(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& board)
{
    // do something with the board
}
```

Answer (score 0):

only the last dimension of an array can be empty in a declare statement, like:

```
int a[]; int b[5][]; int c[3][4][];
```

so, if you need to do that, consider the 'main' prototype:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

change other dimensions in the declaration to *.